# Exact meaning of good for you

Tags: grammar, expressions

I told my friend, today I went for shopping. He replied me “Good for You”. Is it rude or normal?

Comment: Completely depends on intonation. Sounds sarcastic to me in this context since it is not earth shattering news

Comment: It could be either. It might be an encouragement or a sarcastic remark. The context and tone would be important there, and if you don't understand how to parse those in English, perhaps you'd care to visit our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Note that if it's not sarcastic it could easily be condescending.

Comment: Condescending, sarcastic, either way it's not particularly nice (unless you've actually been struggling to go shopping for some time).

Answer (score 0):

In this context, there is two options :

- You friend would have loved to join you but since you didn't invite him/her, he/she is angry at you

or

- He/She doesn't care about you doing your shopping and what you bought

I don't find *this* very offensive but there is kinder ways to tell someone that you aren't interested in what they say. This is one of the shortest.

Comment: There is a third possibility. As a reply, "good for you" could mean, literally, what it says, by way of "that's nice" or just "good." Only intonation could reveal the intent behind the statement.

Comment: @LittleEva Probably not in this context. "*In have a new job !*" "*Good for you.*" There I agree, but not for going shopping...

Comment: Its a common utterance of positive acknowledgment in the U.S. So, I find it a distinct possibility---but again, only intonation would clarify.